# Swift: UIActivityViewController with HTML content

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

How can send an email with HTML text? I use this code to send email from my swift application:

```
let subject = "Email test"
        let content = "This is some text that I want to share."

        // set up activity view controller
        let objectsToShare = [content]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.setValue(subject, forKey: "Subject")
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

        // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop]

        // present the view controller
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want that the content had some HTML tags and to be interpreted as HTML.

How can I do that? Can anyone please provide me an exmaple?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer but if you are, you just have to put the html tags around your content:

```
let content = "<html><body>This is some text that I want to share.</body></html>"
```

You can also create a subclass of UIActivityItemProvider so you can convert the html to an NSAttributedString depending on the application (e.g. the mail app supports html, but for the notes app you can convert it to an NSAttributedString).